# Registration form isn't properly Connecting to MySQL

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, css

Ok, so I've successfully linked a Contact Form for my website to a MySQL database and I'm super stoked about figuring it out, ***however*** on my registration page my code isn't working. I ran this connection check:

```
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{  
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();  
} else {
      echo "It's Working!";
}
```

and it says: "It's working!" So i know i've established a connection to my SQL database.

Let me try to clarify further:

I've got 2 main files for this particular program (obviously we won't be needing to care about styles.css or the linked files for other pages in my site): **register.php** and **db.php**. Here is my code for both. It's simply a project website so i don't care if people see/use my code... It's not working anyway so knock yourselves out, LOL!

First, **db.php**:

```
    define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
    define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
    define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
    define('DB_DATABASE', 'forms1');
    $db = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);
```

Now here's the php in **register.php**, which I've place at the top BEFORE any HTML at all:

```
    include ("db.php"); 

    $msg = "";
    if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
    {
        $name = $_POST["name"];
        $lname = $_POST["lname"];
        $a1 = $_POST["a1"];
        $a2 = $_POST["a2"];
        $city = $_POST["city"];
        $state = $_POST["state"];
        $zip = $_POST["zip"];
        $phone = $_POST["phone"];
        $email = $_POST["email"];
        $password = $_POST["password"];

        $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $name);
        $lname = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $lname);
        $a1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $a1);
        $a2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $a2);
        $city = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $city);
        $state = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $state);
        $zip = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $zip);
        $phone = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $phone);
        $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $email);
        $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $password);
        $password = md5($password);


        $sql="SELECT email FROM users WHERE email='$email'";
        $result=mysqli_query($db,$sql);
        $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1)
        {
            $msg = "Sorry...This email already exist...";
        }
        else
        {
            $query = mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO users(name,lname,a1, a2, city, state, zip, phone, email, password) VALUES ('$name', '$lname', '$a1', '$a2', '$city', '$state', '$zip', '$phone', '$email', '$password')");
            if($query)
            {
                $msg = "Thank You! you are now registered.";
            }
        }
    }
    mysqli_close($db);
```

I should probably mention that JavaScript is included in the HEAD section of my HTML:

```
    (function(H){H.className=H.className.replace(/\bno-js\b/,'js')})(document.documentElement)

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('form.required-form').simpleValidate({
          errorElement: 'em',
          ajaxRequest: true,
          completeCallback: function($el) {
          var formData = $el.serialize();
          }
        });
    });
    $("form[name='form1']").submit(function(){

    .... JS code ....
    return error;
    });
    </script>
    <script type= "text/javascript">
var RecaptchaOptions = {
theme: 'clean'
};
```

Well, I tried to include the HTML code for the form but it wasn't appearing properly, but *believe me when i tell you* that ALL the inputs of the the form fields have a name="" that corresponds to the fields within my table within my database within MySQL. The HTML is most certainly not the problem. I've check syntax and spelling over and over. It's not the HTML. Somewhere there is an error, though.

PLEASE HELP!!!

Thank you all very much.

-Maj

P.S. I purposely deleted the opening and closing php/html tags here in these examples so it'd be easier to read, but i have them placed in my original code.

Comment: Try to add a '<input type="hidden">' to your form and check for it in ‘register.php’ instead of checking for `$_POST["submit"]`; I can't see you js code, but it is possible that the `$_POST["submit"]` value is not sent.

Comment: You don't mention what form the "not working" takes. Error messages? Missing data in tables after the INSERT statement? Anything else?

Can you retrieve the insert ID after the insert?

In general, I would also suggest you harden your code to defeat SQL injection attempts.

Comment: Two general suggestion: 1) never check for `<input type="submit">` when js is involved; 2) check before your script without js and, if it works fine, **then** add js code.

Answer (score 0):

After that if($query){ } block try adding else { print(mysqli_error($db)); } 
perhaps there's an error, but what is the response you got from register.php?

Answer (score 0):

you should start to debug your source code, but if you don't use a debugger, put some "die(SOME VARIABLE);" to locate your trouble area and without javascript, for the first. Just use some simple html-formular and to get row datas, put the answer into <PRE> tags ( or use curl in a terminal, i like this way, but for you it is not necessary ).

If you don't debug your php-code or you your browser-relevant-code, means "html, css, javascript, ..." (you can see with firebug, what data you are sending and what is coming back), you can use echo "INSERT .... BLA ...$VAR ...;" and copy-paste the SQL-Statement and testing it in PhpMyAdmin, to see you get a proper statement, maybe there is a type-converting-problem or many other thinks are possible.

If everything is going well, it is probably some trouble in your javascript-code. But probably you need to convert a type of some variable, you should copy and paste your SQL-Statement and execute it in phpmyadmin to make a verification of your SQL-Statements which you put in your Php-Code. Cheers.